# What is this diamond-like shape called?

Tags: geometry, terminology

What is this shape called?

[image]

I'm just trying to research how to properly constrain it in Fusion 360, and I don't even know what to search for.

Comment: I would call it a diamond.

Comment: isn't a diamond typically 4 sides?

Comment: @MattiP. except that a diamond is usually in reference to a [rhombus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombus), a quadrilateral.  This has six sides, not four.  I don't know of a more specific name than 'non-regular hexagon.'

Comment: It is a hexagon.

Comment: A stretched (irregular) hexagon.

Comment: To be more precise, I would call it an irregular, convex hexagon.

Answer (score 2):

Calling this shape an "irregular hexagon" (as in the comments), while technically correct, doesn't seem to do its regularity properties justice.  It's opposite sides are parallel and equal.

According to Wikipedia this shape could be classified as a parallelogon.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogon.

To be more specific it is a 6-sided convex parallelogon.